# How to apply if-else function for multiples "if statement" and two different dataframes sizes?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have two dataframes of different sizes:

```
`> df1 <- dput(head(public_t))
 structure(list(zona = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), renda_fa = c(2732.58, 
 3579.58, 3579.58, 2323.9, 2323.9, 6000), decile_rank = c(3L, 
 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L), distancia = c(4260.03, 3173.1, 3173.1, 
 21562.81, 
 21562.81, 2696.04)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("zona", 
 "renda_fa", 
 "decile_rank", "distancia"))`

`> df2 <- dput(head(cost))
 structure(list(decile = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), cost_tpublic = 
 c(10.5, 
 7.1, 6.1, 5.6, 4.8, 4.2), cost_tprivate = c(11.6, 10.6, 10.2, 
 11.5, 12.4, 12.5)), .Names = c("decile", "cost_tpublic", 
 "cost_tprivate"
 ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

I need to return the value from df2$cost_tpublic correspondent to df1$decile_rank, in a new column in df1.

How might I do that?
Thank you!

I would expect something like this

```
`> df1 <- dput(head(public_t))
structure(list(zona = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), renda_fa = c(2732.58, 
3579.58, 3579.58, 2323.9, 2323.9, 6000), decile_rank = c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L), distancia = c(4260.03, 3173.1, 3173.1, 
21562.81, 
21562.81, 2696.04)), **percentage_income = c(6.1, 5.6, 5.6, 7.1, 
NA)**, class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("zona", 
"renda_fa", 
"decile_rank", "distancia", "percentage_income"))`
```

Comment: Is the expected output right? I don't understand why the first `decile_rank` equal `3` gives `percentage_income == 5.6` when `cost_tpublic` for decile 3 is `6.1`.

Comment: Thank you, Rui! You are right! I edited it. Would you know how to write the function?

Comment: Done, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `match`.

```
i <- match(df1$decile_rank, df2$decile)
df2$cost_tpublic[i]
#[1] 6.1 5.6 5.6 7.1 7.1  NA
```

So just assign the result to the new column. Now as a one-liner.

```
df1$percentage_income <- df2$cost_tpublic[match(df1$decile_rank, df2$decile)]
```

**Data.**

I am reposting the data because I couldn't copy&paste from the question, there are some unwanted characters. Note that the final dataframe is named `df1b`.

```
df1 <- 
 structure(list(zona = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), renda_fa = c(2732.58, 
 3579.58, 3579.58, 2323.9, 2323.9, 6000), decile_rank = c(3L, 
 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L), distancia = c(4260.03, 3173.1, 3173.1, 
 21562.81,  21562.81, 2696.04)), 
class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("zona",  "renda_fa", 
"decile_rank", "distancia"))

df2 <- 
 structure(list(decile = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
cost_tpublic =  c(10.5, 7.1, 6.1, 5.6, 4.8, 4.2), 
cost_tprivate = c(11.6, 10.6, 10.2, 11.5, 12.4, 12.5)), 
.Names = c("decile", "cost_tpublic", "cost_tprivate"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df1b <-
structure(list(zona = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), renda_fa = c(2732.58, 
3579.58, 3579.58, 2323.9, 2323.9, 6000), decile_rank = c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L), distancia = c(4260.03, 3173.1, 3173.1, 21562.81, 
21562.81, 2696.04), percentage_income = c(5.6, 4.8, 4.8, 7.1, 
7.1, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rui!
I was trying to do something like:

    `carro$percentage = with(carro, ifelse(decile_renda == 1, decile_renda*0.116,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 2, decile_renda*0.106,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 3, decile_renda*0.102,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 4, decile_renda*0.115,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 5, decile_renda*0.124,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 6, decile_renda*0.125,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 7, decile_renda*0.137,
     ifelse(decile_renda == 8, decile_renda*0.141,0))))))))))

I excluded the last one because of the characters limitation.
Thank you!

Comment: Instead of lots of `if else`, consider `case_when` from the tidyverse package.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be `left_join` to pull in data from df2 to df1. Then `select` then columns you'd like to retain.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c('decile_rank' = 'decile'))
```